# How do I dynamically select a completion function in zsh?

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, zsh-completion

Say I have a script `foo` which can be called as:

```
foo git clone http://example.com
```

or as:

```
foo print 12
```

etc.

How can I make a `compdef` that delegates to `$argv[0]` here to allow it to handle completion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redispatch into the normal completion system by calling the `_normal` function, but first you need to modify some of the state so that it will ignore your program name and possibly its arguments.  A very simple version of this can be done with:

```
#compdef foo
shift words
(( CURRENT-- ))
_normal
```

If you need to get more complicated that that (which is likely), you can take a look at the completion definitions for other commands that call `_normal`, such as the completions for `env`, `sudo`, or `fakeroot`.