# ZSH Equivalent to Bash `_command` completion

Tags: shell, zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

Given an example wrapper shell function:

```
app() {
    setsid "$@"
}
```

In Bash, you can do `complete -F _command app` to automatically give `app` completions for all commands (not just binaries on the path but also the arguments afterwards).

How can you do this in ZSH? I have some leads with `_normal` and `-command-line-` but I've been unable to figure out the correct command to put in a `.zshrc`.

Update:

Just wanted to document something interesting, this produces a SIGSEGV:

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit
compdef _normal app

# Attempt tab completion of app:
# _normal:1: maximum nested function level reached; increase FUNCNEST?

FUNCNEST=999

# Attempt tab completion of app again
# !!! ZSH crashes (see coredumpctl) !!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated shorter answer:**

Turns out `_command` actually does exist in ZSH as well! I didn't find the manpages very clear on this but here's your answer:

```
# Set up autocomplete
autoload -U compinit && compinit
compdef _command app
```

It's also helpful to note that after `compinit` you can run `echo $_comps[ls]` to get the completion command of any command (the output here is `_ls`).

**Original answer:**

Figured it out:

```
# Set up autocomplete
_app() {
    shift words
    (( CURRENT-- ))
    _normal
}
autoload -U compinit && compinit
compdef _app app
```

This was somewhat a duplicate of this question: [How do I dynamically select a completion function in zsh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547410/how-do-i-dynamically-select-a-completion-function-in-zsh)

If someone knows a shorter solution like what Bash has then please answer as that would be nice.